# Sending emails with django

Tags: python, django

I am building an app with django and i have build a contact form on the app which allows users to contact by just sending an email. Everything works fine but the problem is, in the received email the senders email is not displayed in the From:sender_email, instead the email in apps settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER is displayed in From:shopvoomhelpdesk@gmail.com, and To:shopvoomhelpdesk@gmail.com.
I have tried to debug the problem but can't understand what is causing the problem.

here is my code in views.py

```
 def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                names = form.cleaned_data['names']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                print(email)
                subject = form.cleaned_data['subject'] 
                message = form.cleaned_data['message']
                message_body = f'Names: {names} \n {message}'
                send_mail(
                    subject, 
                    message_body, 
                    email,
                    [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER], 
                    fail_silently=True
                )
                return render(request, 'sunyata/success.html')
            except Exception as e:
                context['form'] = EmailForm(request.POST)
                context['error'] = 'Unable to send message, it might be due to spelling error in\
                                        email check your email and resend again'
                return render(request, 'sunyata/success.html', context)
        else:
            form = EmailForm(request.POST)
            context['form'] = form
            return render(request, 'sunyata/contact.html', context)
    else:
        context['form'] = EmailForm()
        return render(request, 'sunyata/contact.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    names = forms.CharField(label='Names',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder':"Enter your names"})) 
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder':'Enter your email'}))
    subject = forms.CharField(label='Subject',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder':"Enter email subject"})) 
    message = forms.CharField(label='Message', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control',
               'placeholder':'Enter your message','rows':"4"}))
```

settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'shopvoomhelpdesk@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD ='emailpassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Gmail "corrects" the `From` address to your accounts email address.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean Klaus

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrongly instead of this:

```
send_mail(subject, message_body, email, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER], fail_silently=True)
```

It should be this:

```
send_mail(subject, message_body, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email], fail_silently=True)
```

as the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#send-mail) say `sender` should be first parameter then the `receiver(s)`.

`EMAIL_HOST_USER` is the sender ( From ) and `email` is the receiver ( To ).